# hangman: beginner in C

Tags: c

I can't seem to figure out why my program won't end the game when the user guesses the all the letters. I know the problem is in the play( ) function. Any pointers on what to change in the play function or whatever is causing this problem?

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <ctype.h>
// MAXWORD, which will be the max word length 
#define     MAXWORD     10
// INCORRECT_GUESSES, which will be the max guesses
#define     INCORRECT_GUESSES   5

/* Prototypes */

// Fills theArray with howMany copies of theLetter
void    fill_array( char *theArray, int howMany, char theLetter );

// Get char from player, checks the letter, shows progress so far
int     get_letter( char *theWord, char *soFar );

// Check if letter is in word, updates progress so far
int     letter_in_word( char *theWord, char *soFar, char theLetter );

// Convert the word to lowercase
void    lower_string( char *someWord );

// Play one game
void    play( char *theWord );

/* Function definitions */

int main( )
{
    char theWord [ MAXWORD ];
    FILE*   word;
    word = fopen( "guesswords.txt", "r" );

    if ( word == NULL )
    {
        printf( "No input file found..........\n" );
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Want to play a game?\n");
    fscanf( word, "%s", theWord );

    lower_string( theWord );

    play( theWord );
    fprintf( word, "%s", theWord);
    fclose( word );
    return 0;
}

// Get char from player, checks the letter, shows progress so far
int get_letter( char *theWord, char *soFar )
{
    char theLetter;
    printf("\nPlease enter a letter: ");
    scanf( " %c", &theLetter );
    theLetter = tolower(theLetter);

    letter_in_word( theWord, soFar, theLetter );

    return theLetter;
}

// Fills theArray with howMany copies of theLetter
void fill_array( char *theArray, int howMany, char theLetter )
{
    int i;
    for( i=0; i<howMany; i++ )
    {
        theArray[i]= theLetter;
        *(theArray + i) = theLetter;
        *theArray = theLetter;
    }
    theArray[howMany] = '\0';
}

// Check if letter is in word, updates progress so far
int letter_in_word( char *theWord, char *soFar, char theLetter )
{
    int i;
    int num=0;
    int len = strlen(theWord);

    for( i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if (theWord[i] == theLetter )
        {
            soFar[i] = theLetter;
            num++;
        }
    }
    if (num == 0)
    {
        printf( "\nSORRY! your letter is not in the word\n" );
        printf("%s\n", soFar);
        return 0;

    }
    else if (num>0)
    {
        printf( "\nCongratz! your letter was in the word\n" );
        printf("%s\n", soFar);
        return 1;
    }
}

// Convert the word to lowercase
void lower_string( char *someWord )
{
    int i, cha;
    int len = strlen( someWord );
    for( i=0; i<len; i++ )
    {
        cha = someWord[i];
        cha = tolower(cha);
        someWord[i] = cha;
    }
}

// Play one game
void play( char *theWord )
{
    int i;
    int len = strlen(theWord);
    int guess = INCORRECT_GUESSES;
    int result = 0;
    char soFar[MAXWORD];
    fill_array( soFar, len, '*');
    printf( "Guess this word: %s\n", soFar ); 

    for( i=0; i<INCORRECT_GUESSES; i++ ) 
    {
        guess = INCORRECT_GUESSES - (i+1);
        get_letter( theWord, soFar );

        if(get_letter<0)
        {
            printf( "\nYou have %d guesses left\n", guess);
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "\nYou have guessed all the letters! You have won!" );
            return;
        }

        if( i == INCORRECT_GUESSES-1)
        {
            printf( "\nSorry, you're out of guesses\nBetter luck next time!\n" ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start the debugger and step through your program.

Comment: Print out the states of variables and ensure they match your expectations. Stack Overflow isn't a debugger; ask here when you have a *specific* question.

Comment: you can try various debugging approaches, running the program using `gdb` (gnu debugger, I believe), running it via `valgrind`, and/or using `strace` to name a few--where you run them like so `gdb ./<PROGRAM NAME>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely have a problem here in `play`:

```
    get_letter( theWord, soFar );

    if(get_letter<0)
    {
        printf( "\nYou have %d guesses left\n", guess);
    }
```

`get_letter` is a function, it returns a value when you call it using `()`. You ignore this value. You then ask if `get_letter` (the *function*) is less than 0. Instead, you need to assign the result of `get_letter` or use it directly:

```
    if (get_letter( theWord, soFar ) < 0)
    {
        printf( "\nYou have %d guesses left\n", guess);
    }
```

But you also definitely have other problems in the code as well. I would suggest that you try stepping through the program as it runs and look at the values and see how your code is working (or not).

Comment: Just to clarify: `get_letter` identifies nothing but the function (or in some cases, a pointer to the function).  It specifically doesn't represent the function's return value.  If you want to remember the return value for later, assign it to a variable, same as you are already doing with `strlen(...)` and `fopen(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be doing anything with the return values from your functions. For example:

```
letter_in_word( theWord, soFar, theLetter );
```

This function returns an integer value (0 or 1), but you aren't assigning it to anything so this information is lost.

The same thing here:

```
get_letter( theWord, soFar );
```